# AutoDesk Premium Reporting APIs returns 403 Error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, aps

When I call contexts API I'm getting 403 forbidden error. Can anyone help me with this issue, please? also, I have premium reporting API permissions.

I have generated the token using 3-legged authentication.

API: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/insights/v1/contexts
Response:

{
"title": "ForbiddenError",
"detail": ""
}

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the callback url right?
Are you the primary or secondary admin under manage.autodesk.com?
Where are you testing endpoints postman or any other platform?